# Communication protocols between two python instances

Tags: python, api, websocket, concurrency, actor

I have a 2 python programs that run in different python instances and talk to each other.

Example:

- **Program 1**: "Hey Program 2, copy this file and send me a report when you are over"
- **Program 2**: "Got it", "Copying", "File copied succesfully on C:\xxx"

(It's really not that simple and it make sense to run them in separate instances).

The current communication protocol that I'm using are `websockets` which is working but it just looks kind of weird in some parts of my code (maybe because it's **not** really a `server-client` communication and more like two `actors` communicating)

What other communication protocols/API/libraries can be used for this purpose?

Comment: If they are running on same system, you can use named pipe..

Comment: You can also check shared memory https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html